# PHP-mysqli_fetch_all() consuming an insane amount of memory. Is this reasonable?

Tags: php, mysql, memory, memory-management

My echo statements in the code below are showing me that my memory usage is reasonable at the points indicated in the code [Point #1 ~= 216728bytes (~217 kb)][Point #2 = 6629952 bytes(~6.629 mb)]. However, suddenly when I call:

> mysqli_fetch_all($ResultObj)

It is followed by the following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in I:\xampp\htdocs\GLS_DBSearchProject\index.php on line 28

It's pretty obvious that this error is telling my that the program is expending PHP's allowed memory usage. It's also obvious that line 28 (Point #3) in the code is to blame (removing just that line solves all of my problems). What isn't obvious however, is how calling mysqli_fetch_all on a single mysqli_result object is using so much memory (by simple subtraction it appears that this single operation is using >=  127587776 bytes (~127 mb) of memory. This seems completely unreasonable. Especially since the database table that I am querying only has a Data length of (16.5 MB) and a total database size of ~62 MB.

I'd appreciate it greatly if someone could tell me what I'm overlooking here. Or explain how this memory usage is actually reasonable.

```
    echo '<br>';
    echo "Memory Usage: " . memory_get_usage() . '<br>'; //Point #1
    $query = "SELECT * FROM scans;";
    $ResultObjList = $AppInstance->DBSets[1]->QuerySet($query);
    echo '<br> DatabaseSet 1 TYPE: ' . print_r($AppInstance->DBSets[1]) . '<br>';
    foreach($ResultObjList as $ResultObj){
        echo '<br>' .get_class($ResultObj);
        echo "Memory Usage: " . memory_get_usage() . '<br>'; //Point #2
        $ResultsAsArray = mysqli_fetch_all($ResultObj); //Point #3

    }
```

Comment: You could try to clear the result sets: mysqli_free_result()

Comment: It depend of number of rows, not necessary of db size. If you have a lot of elements in array, exhaust memory is reasonable. how many rows returns your query?

Comment: 100114 Rows are returned. So you're saying that it's reasonable for an array holding this to possibly consume 127 mb?

Comment: @BrandonSnider absolutely yes. use single fetch instead of `mysqli_fetch_all ` (or ingrement memory, but if your db increment, you will have same problem in future)

Comment: Alright thanks. That tells me what I need to know. That's a bummer because I'm going to have to work around individual fetches. So, why does it take so much memory to make a 100114 element array?...Actually, I think I figured it out, but this question may not be a bad place for someone to post a good answer to that question.

Comment: Basically, arrays in PHP versions < 7.0 take up far too much memory.  It's better in 7.0+ but still not ideal.  I faced a similar issue recently and one thing that helps if you really need to store all the results in memory at once is to `foreach` the result set, but then store each row serialized in a new array.  Then just unserialize it one row at a time as you need it.  This will take drastically less memory than a regular array.   Of course, YMMV but it's worth considering.

Comment: @AlanHorrocks Thanks for the info. I considered that approach. It seems to be a good one if you need the data stored in memory. Fortunately, running into this issue made me question whether I actually needed all of the information in memory, and I reached the conclusion that there was a better solution. For anyone trying to do the same thing as I was, when you need to query multiple databases simultaneously, you can use the UNION command in SQL and then organize the results via SQL resulting in only a single mysql_result object. Since the obj. is already organized it should be ready 4 output.